# AndEngine Texture very strange

Tags: android, textures, andengine

[image: Strange Error]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Code to load image:

```
 gameOverAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(
                activity.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024,
                TextureOptions.DEFAULT);

deathScreen1 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createFromAsset(gameOverAtlas, activity,
                        "deathscreen1.png");

engine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(
            this.gameOverAtlas);
    engine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(
            this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture);
    engine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(
            this.gameOverAtlas);

    try {
        this.gameTextureAtlas
                .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                        0, 1, 0));
        this.gameTextureAtlas.load();

        this.gameOverAtlas
                .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                        0, 1, 0));
        this.gameOverAtlas.load();

        this.playerAtlas
                .build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(
                        0, 1, 0));
        this.playerAtlas.load();

    } catch (final TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }
}
```

Then attaching the sprite:

```
gameOverScreen =  new Sprite(0, 0, 650, 400, ResourceManager.getInstance().deathScreen1,vbom);

    attachChild(gameOverScreen);
```

I get this error:
[image]

Comment: I can't see any error in you code snipped. Do you always use the `BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas` or why not just the `BitmapTextureAtlas`? but this can't be it. How do you load the atlas afterwards ( `gameOverAtlas.load()` )?  The only situations where I get a distorted image like you, is when the atlas doesn't load properly or the texture is too big for the atlas. But then the app always throws an exception.

Comment: Edited to include how I load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are calling loadTexture before building the texture atlas.

move:

```
engine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(
        this.gameOverAtlas);
engine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(
        this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture);
engine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(
        this.gameOverAtlas);
```

after the try/Catch block.

Also if your texture is the same size as the dimensions of the TextureAltas it will fail unless you set the padding and spacing parameters to 0.

As an aside, if you are making a texture atlas that contains only a single texture region, there is no need to use a buildable texture atlas.

The special feature of the BuildableTexture atlas is that it will fit many regions for you into the atlas, meaning you do not need to use a program like TexturePacker and teh texturePacker extension for andengine.

Comment: Above, you left out the "BUILD" part of using a buildable texture atlas in your code example. Are you ever calling it? It does not work without it. Not "load()" but "build()"

Comment: The weird ness now is no longer their but instead a black box for all the built textures

Comment: Oh - I know that error. Your Texture atlas is not bigger than your texture. Remeber to account for the padding and spacing. For fun, try making it 1048x1048.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26500/discussion-between-nmyster-and-plastic-sturgeon)

Answer (score 0):

Since its buildable texture, not normal one, you are loading it with bit different way

```
try
{           
    gameTexture.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 1));
    gameTexture.load();
}
catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e)
{
    Debug.e(e);
}
```

Keep in mind those 3 last parameters, you can control padding etc.